# Kubernetes, Connecting a frontend application php code to a backend server php code

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Right now I am trying to host simple site using kubernetes. My application has a simple php file running both on frontend and backend. My frontend php file wants to access the backend php file and I am creating an ajax request to do the same. But not able to figure out what base-url I need to specify(for kubernetes) in my ajax call to access the backend.

My current setup:

1. Created two container images, one for frontend code and another for backend.
2. Pushed these images to my gcr.
3. Started a Kubernetes cluster. Setup yaml files for frontend RC and service, and backend RC and service
4. We are able to access both the services independently with their external IPs by running kubectl commands.
5. But our front end has not been able to communicate with the backend service.
6. Not sure whether we need a dns server?? How to set it up if you think we need one.

## Backend service yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  `labels:
      name: mytestapp-be
   name: mytestapp-be-service
spec:
   ports:
     - port: 80 
       targetPort: 80
       protocol: TCP
   selector:
      app: mytestapp-be        
      tier: backend
```

I have created a service with above file. And my frontend application code, has an ajax snippet which carries a url to access the backend file using service name and port name.

```
url: "http://mytestapp-be-service:80",
```

Comment: You could use a service of type Clusterip for your backend and just use that in your frontend code to make AJAX calls to. Within the cluster, that service IP should resolve correctly.

Answer (score 2):

normally, on a completely provisioned kubernetes cluster you should have dns working out of the box. If you deployed front and back in the same namespace, your pods should be able to communicate simply by service name. The problem you might be facing here is that when you open a page on a browser and attempt a request from it, simply by pointing to you backend service, you try to make this request **from the browser**  which is not inside of the kubernetes cluster, and can not reach other pods by means of in-kubernetes networking.

If that is the case, you need to expose both front and backend, so both of them are accessible by the browser (there are a couple of ways to actually do that, starting with nodePort services, via LB services to Ingress.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But both my frontend and backend are exposed and are on the same cluster. I can create services for both of them and am able to run it on the browser independently. But I don't know how to connect both the services, especially what url I need to give in my application code(say index.php which I have packaged inside a container image) to access the backend using ajax.

Comment: so, how are you exposing them ? cause from what you wrote it seems you use ClusterIP services which do not expose the service/pods outside of cluster

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to pinpoint your problem if you post your yamls here. But here some general information:

The ease of internal service discovery is one of the strengths of kubernetes. For communication from inside a container to another service in k8s you can use the built in DNS or environment variables. DNS works as following: The service is available by its name and it resolves to the cluster IP of the service. So if your service name is `backendservice` you should be able to reach its cluster IP by that name from within the cluster (under the specified namespace, if you chose one, e.g. `backendservice.my-namespace`). The service port(s) should forward to the defined target port(s) of the pods that are part of the service. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backendservice
spec:
  selector:
    name: nginxphppod
  ports:
    - name: http 
      port: 80 
      targetPort: 80
```

The service will be available by pointing your frontend to `http://backendservice:80`

For more information please read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

To trouble shoot run `kubectl get svc` and double check that all your services have a clusterIP assigned. This should be the case if you did not specify `clusterIP: None` in your service yaml.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. So you mean if I have an ajax request in my frontend php file(inside the container) for the backend php file(again inside a container), that ajax url has to be http://[backendservicename]:portname.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, assuming the service has a clusterIP and you are serving on the target port inside the POD, e.g. with Nginx or something else.

Comment: I have edited my question to post my backend service yaml file and my ajax url code snippet. My frontend container has a php file (which has a button) . When I render my frontend service and rc using kubectl commands, I get an external ip. I am using this this external ip in the browser to see my frontend webpage. Now when I click the button on the frontend page, I am expecting it to go and fetch the data from my backend service file. so that is what I am expecting my ajax call to do

Comment: I think you have a typo in front of `labels` in your yaml. Also you probably need to also post your backend deployment yaml and possibly the nginx (or other webserver) configuration of your backend for a better analysis of the issue. And what happens to your ajax call? Does it time out or give you an error?

Comment: I am using apache server. Can you please tell me where exactly this conf file is being referred to and how to configure it for apache server. In one of the documents on kubernetes, I see an nginx conf file and the name of the file is same as frontend deployment/service. Does it implicitly take the conf file with same name as frontend deployment/service? This part is not very clear